# Make history table with Mysql

Tags: php, mysql, performance, codeigniter

I'm trying to make several history tables with MYSQL but the performance is terrible. I'm probably not doing it right.

Currently I have the following table:

```
id_user     cash_d0     cash_d1   cash_d2  ...  cash_d135
1             1500        800       400    ...     200
2             50          NULL      NULL   ...     NULL
```

Every night I add the cash of the current user to `cash_d0` and I set `cash_d2` to the value of `cash_d1`, `cash_d1` to `cash_d0`.... This "shift" operation takes a lot of time.

Is there a way to optimize this shift operation? Or even a better way to build my tables?

I need to keep history over 135 days and I have about 10 similar tables, tracking history of different variables and each table has 136 columns.

The shift is done by the following line (using Codeigniter) :

```
$this->db->set('cash_d1', 'IFNULL('cash_d1, 0)' + `cash_d0'`, FALSE);
```

Note: When the table is created on day 0, all columns are set to `NULL`, this is way I need to handle the `NULL` values.

Comment: Any time you have enumerated column names, alarm bells should start ringing. See normalisation.

Comment: Change the design to have one cash column and add a new column to identify which cash item it is.

Comment: use   a table which have `id_user,   date , cash` three column. this will distinguish date wise cash for different users. Also cash column default value must be 0 (easy to handle rather than null )